# Exporting large map area in several smaller pages?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts

I have a large area at the scale 1:5000 which fits in a size larger than A0. I want to export it from ArcGIS into A3 pages at 1:5000. Below is in detail the exact area of what i am looking for and the position of the pages (which overlap) http://prntscr.com/cynt24 .

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is to create Data Driven Pages.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/creating-data-driven-pages.htm

Is not hard so this might be enough.

Once you read the link the question is how to "make" the different windows. As far as I Know there are 2 easy ways:

First, create a polygon shapefile, draw a rectangle and do it the shape and size you want for the "windows" copy and paste this one as many times as you need and use this as the frame of your future driven pages. 
Second, you can use Strip Map Index which, basically, creates the "windows" automatically by following a feature (a line.. polygons..) but I'm not gonna get into this one because creating the frames with rectangles is much easier and will fit better for your area.

I hope this helps, if not, let me know and I'll explain how data driven pages works better.

Comment: Thanks i have managed doing them by using Grid Index Features from that menu and created a bunch of polygons in the A3 format. Then i just mvoed them to where i needed to.

Comment: Cool, I'm happy it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can try Data Driven pages to create a mapbook
see the link below for the ESRI website
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/what-are-data-driven-pages-.htm

You can use this to create a custom grid of each A3 page area and set the scale for each page.